# Html and Javascript : combine button and js fucntion code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have an html register form and i want to add those data to my mySql database.

this is my html

```html
<form>
  <div class="inputs">
    <div class="input">
      <input placeholder="Email" id="email" type="text">
      <img src="img/mail.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input placeholder="username" id="username" type="text">
      <img src="img/user.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input placeholder="password" id="password" type="password">
      <img src="img/pass.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="insert()">Register</button>
</form>
<script src="js/insertUser.js"></script>
```

I need to call the javascript insert function when the button is clicked

this is my javascript script

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "assessments"
});

function insert() {

  username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  email = document.getElementById("email").value;

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql =
      "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (username, password, email)";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      alert("1 record inserted");
    });
  });
}
```

My question is how to combine them so when the  html button is clicked to call the js function. I mean where do I place this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick event on your button should be calling the javascript function. Did you correctly link your script file from your html file?
Try replacing`<script language = "javascript">` to just `<script>`

Comment: i just edit my code. i call ``` <script src="js/insertUser.js"></script>``` after the end of the form..but still doesnt work.. also is my js file synstax correct?

Comment: Calling the script file seems good. You only use the <script> tag inside of  a HTML file, however, so try removing both the script tags in your js file (the one at the start and the end of your js file). Hope that works for you. This link might help you if you are getting lost: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-use-external-js-files-in-an-HTML-file

Comment: nope it changes nothing..like my button is dead..i dont get any response

Comment: Hmm take a look at the link I sent , that may help you out. Otherwise I am not too sure really. Check the console using the inspector in Chrome to see if an actual error message is reported.

Comment: nope, i am confused. im so sure that my code is right. I dont get where the error is. btw thanks for your time